# Best Practice: When to throw away unwanted data from asynchronous call

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have some asynchronous middleware that accesses a remote api and dispatches it to a Redux.

I am accessing an existing api which returns a large chunk of data, much of it that I do not need. Is there any established best practice for when to discard unwanted elements from the data? As far as I can see I could:

1 - Filter it out when received and only pass what I need to the store.

2 - Store everything in the store when it is received and use a selector or mapStateToProps to extract only what I need to render.

3 - Store and extract everything and filter out what I need within the component.

What do others think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can't change the API to use something like streams or at least pagination, go with option no. 1.

- Try to work with the least amount of data necessary to do the
  job. This is a general rule and doesn't apply only to
  redux!
- Try to keep your store as flat as possible.
- Try to minimize the data involved in any actions that lead to a change in the store

With that said, filter out all unused data right when the API response comes in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a large amount of data something like this from the API:

**API**

```
"payload": {
"info": [ ... large ...],
"meta": [ ... small ...],
}
```

The in your Redux action action make sure to use only the small data. For instance in your reducer

**Reducer**

```
function reducer(store, action) {
  switch (action.payload) {
    case 'GET_API':
      store = {...store, meta: action.payload.meta }
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return store
}
```

So now, you wont have that large data anymore, once that API is finished, the reducer will only contain the the small data.